# What tags to use to display one item ONLY in the template?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

am using helper in my template like this

```
Template.walkthrough.helpers({
     item: function () {
        // some code here
     }
});
```

if item were more than one item, i would user {{#each}} {{/each}} to navigate through all the items in the "item" and use {{elementName}} to display the element value i want.

My problem is that item has only one document value. what is the correct tags to use in the template to display "item" information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `{{item.property}}` syntax in the HTML. For example, if you return a post from your collection of posts, subsequently this post has a title, in order to display it in the HTML use `{{post.title}}`